# Outputting values of select options in specific HTML structure on selection

Tags: javascript, html

I want to output the values that become visible when selecting an option in the dropdown into the table structure that is now visible as an example. **Edit:** *The table is just as an example how I want the output to be after selecting an option, I don’t want the table to -always- be visible and insert selections into it. So my guess is that the table structure should be set up after .innerHTML or something and declare the values at the right places into the table?*

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```js
function selectedAfternoon(element) {
  var text = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("output-selected-option-afternoon").innerHTML = "<div>" + text.split("|").join("</div><div>") + "</div>";
  document.getElementById("output-selected-option-afternoon").querySelector("div:last-child").classList.add("price-selected-option")
}
```

```css
.selected-option {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<select id="namiddag" name="Namiddag" data-name="Namiddag" class="js-basic-single select-namiddag" onChange="selectedAfternoon(this);">
  <option></option>
  <option id="13x19namiddag" value="13x19 cm|1|12,50">13x19 cm, €12.50</option>
  <option id="20x30namiddag" value="20x30 cm|1|22,50">20x30 cm, €22.50</option>
  <option id="30x45namiddag" value="30x45 cm|1|32,50">30x45 cm, €32.50</option>
  <option class="disabled" value="disabled" disabled="disabled">Wil je meer stuks of formaten van deze foto? Vermeld dit dan in de winkelwagen., &nbsp;</option>
</select>

<div id="output-selected-option-afternoon" class="selected-option"></div>


<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Format</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>13x19 cm</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="price-selected-option">12,50</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

```js
function selectedAfternoon(element) {
  var text = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
  let tableBody = document.getElementById('selected-option-table-afternoon');

  const [format, amount, price] = text.split("|")

  tableBody.innerHTML = `<tr>
                <td>${format}</td>
                <td>${amount}</td>
                <td>${price}</td>
                </tr>`
}

function selectedCommute(element) {
  var text = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
  let tableBody = document.getElementById('selected-option-table-commute');

  const [format, amount, price] = text.split("|")

  tableBody.innerHTML = `<tr>
                <td>${format}</td>
                <td>${amount}</td>
                <td>${price}</td>
                </tr>`
}
```

```html
<select id="namiddag" name="Namiddag" data-name="Namiddag" class="js-basic-single select-namiddag" onChange="selectedAfternoon(this);">
  <option></option>
  <option id="13x19namiddag" value="13x19 cm|1|12,50">13x19 cm, €12.50</option>
  <option id="20x30namiddag" value="20x30 cm|1|22,50">20x30 cm, €22.50</option>
  <option id="30x45namiddag" value="30x45 cm|1|32,50">30x45 cm, €32.50</option>
  <option class="disabled" value="disabled" disabled="disabled">Wil je meer stuks of formaten van deze foto? Vermeld dit dan in de winkelwagen., &nbsp;</option>
</select>

<select id="onderweg" name="Onderweg" data-name="Onderweg" class="js-basic-single select-onderweg" onChange="selectedCommute(this);">
  <option></option>
  <option id="13x19onderweg" value="13x19 cm|1|12,50">13x19 cm, €12.50</option>
  <option id="20x30onderweg" value="20x30 cm|1|22,50">20x30 cm, €22.50</option>
  <option id="30x45onderweg" value="30x45 cm|1|32,50">30x45 cm, €32.50</option>
  <option class="disabled" value="disabled" disabled="disabled">Wil je meer stuks of formaten van deze foto? Vermeld dit dan in de winkelwagen., &nbsp;</option>
</select>

<div id="output-selected-option-afternoon" class="selected-option">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Format</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="selected-option-table-afternoon">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="price-selected-option"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="output-selected-option-commute" class="selected-option">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Format</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="selected-option-table-commute">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="price-selected-option"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: should it only display 1 option at a time?

Comment: Hey @GrafiCode, yes :-)

Comment: Hey @GrafiCode, do you have some time to find a solution for this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside your selectedAfternoon function

```
  function selectedAfternoon(element) {
            var text = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
            let tableBody = document.querySelector('tbody');

            const [format, amount, price] = text.split("|")

            tableBody.innerHTML = `<tr>
                <td>${format}</td>
                <td>${amount}</td>
                <td>${price}</td>
                </tr>`
        }
```

Comment: I added the code inside my function and deleted the table (which was just as an example of how I want my output after selection to be like) but then I get an script error. Your code also doesn’t involve the -th- heading tags and my class in the last -td- tag. There must be an easier way also to do this? Isn’t there a possibility to add the html structure after “.innerHTML” and then insert the right values at the right places with some sort of value selector/importer?

Comment: it has not thead, because of i am changing just tbody...
i gave you outline how to do, you can easily continue from there

Comment: Hi @n1koloza, sorry, but even when I copied your code into the function and move my table into div with class .selected-option it does not work. I get [object HTMLTableRowElement] message as seen in this screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oyLVeP12yeXM3uobdYyuZoAPQHakKwEe/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: i have updated code, check it, tested and it works :D

Comment: Awesome @n1koloza! It does :-) How can I give the table a class so I can add styling to it with CSS? Just targeting table wouldn’t be a good option in case I have multiple tables on my page.

Comment: you can add class or id inside html and than get it with js.and using classList.add you can add class

Comment: Oh yes of course… I was just thinking that too haha after I commented, sorry. Should be easy. Thank you very much for this!

Comment: Hey @n1koloza, so it’s working, yes, but I have more then 1 dropdown and they all should act the same. But when I now select an option in for example the second dropdown (see the new snippet I have just added) it displays the outcome in the first table. Do you have a fix for this? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes... 
querySelector returns first tbody... 
so give to tbody id or class and instead of getting querySelector('tbody') get with them with classes or id

Comment: I tried that, but when I then/now select an option the TH titles disappear..

Comment: See updated (second) snippet

Comment: give that id's to tbody tags

Comment: Yay! Of course. Thank you =D